# Javascript/Jquery won't change URL parameters in Safari but it will in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, safari

I have this JQuery/JS script that changes $_GET parameters of URL depending on which option from select element is selected. It works fine in Chrome but it won't change $_GET parameters or refresh in Safari 6.1.6.

```
 $("#promjena").change(function () {
    var v = $("#promjena").val();
    var href = window.location.href;

    if (v === "1") {
        if (href.includes("?akcija=kontrola")) {
            window.location.href = href.replace("?akcija=kontrola", "?akcija=default");
        } else if (href.includes("?akcija=signal")) {
            window.location.href = href.replace("?akcija=signal", "?akcija=default");
        } else {
            window.location.href = window.location.href + "?akcija=default";
        }
    }
    if (v === "2") {
        if (href.includes("?akcija=default")) {
            window.location.href = href.replace("?akcija=default", "?akcija=kontrola");
        } else if (href.includes("?akcija=signal")) {
            window.location.href = href.replace("?akcija=signal", "?akcija=kontrola");
        } else {
            window.location.href = window.location.href + "?akcija=kontrola";
        }
    }
    if (v === "3") {
        if (href.includes("?akcija=default")) {
            window.location.href = href.replace("?akcija=default", "?akcija=signal");
        } else if (href.includes("?akcija=kontrola")) {
            window.location.href = href.replace("?akcija=kontrola", "?akcija=signal");
        } else {
            window.location.href = window.location.href + "?akcija=signal";
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you isolate the problem a little further by doing `console.log(v, href)` inside the change event handler and checking the values? Add it just before the `if`

Comment: Console log returns: undefined undefined.

Comment: You have to place `console.log` after  `var v = $("#promjena").val();var href = window.location.href;` these two lines. Have you already placed it there?

Comment: I'm sorry, i've placed it wrong. This is the return: 3http://localhost/papirus/kontrolna_lista/index.php?akcija=kontrola

Comment: Can you try `var v = String($("#promjena").val());` or `var v = $("#promjena").val() + "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One chance is that `val()` is returning a number and you are expecting a string in `if(v === "1")` if thats an issue you can do:

```
 var v = $('#promjena').val() + ''; //to convert to string if not
```

Another chance is the [support for includes in Safari < 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

If that is the case you can use a polyfill for `includes` as mentioned in the above page, or rewrite your code like:

```
if(href.indexOf("?akcija=default") !== -1)
```

Or use any other alternatives from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789952/427146)

Comment: It gets in the if(v==="1") but it won't go further than      
   `if (href.includes("?akcija=kontrola")) {`. I have ?akcija="kontrola" in the URL.

Comment: use `if(href.indexOf("?akcija=default") !== -1)` instead of `includes` *(which is a newer addition to Javascript that is not supported in older browsers)* . But you can polyfill it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
     var v = $("#promjena").attr("value");
```

OR

```
     var v = parseInt($("#promjena").attr("value")).toString();
```

OR

```
    var v = parseInt($("#promjena").val()).toString();
```